# Unity Tilemap one way collisions

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, collision-detection, physics

How can we get one way collisions using Tilemaps in Unity?

There doesn't seem to be much online regarding this topic yet.

From this link: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1471156/how-to-make-one-way-platforms-using-a-tilemap.html, I got that we should use a Tilemap Collider 2D for collisions and not use a Composite Collider 2D. Finally, we need a Platform Effector 2D with One-Way enabled.

However, the resulting tiles all behave like normal tiles in that collisions occur along all edges.

Here's what the inspector looks like for the tile map in question.
[image: Inspector for the One Way Tilemap]

The scene setup looks like this:
[image]

It looks like the tiles in the scene all have collision edges all the way around.

What needs to be done to allow for one way platforms? Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is the setup of the character:

[image]

Here is a view of what it looks like in game:
When jumping, the character unfortunately collides with the block above and is unable to pass through.

[image]

Comment: Just to confirm, have you actually run the game to test your effect?
Could you also show the setup of your character/object that you say collides in every direction?

There's nothing glaringly wrong with your tilemap setup.

Comment: @andeart thanks for the response! I have run the game to test the effect. I've updated the question to include the character's setup. Could it be one of the settings belonging to the Rigidbody2D or BoxCollider2D?

Comment: Hmm... your character is a Kinematic rigid-body. I wonder if that is a factor here. I can confirm that your tilemap approach itself is fine (unless it's a sneaky/silly mistake that is hard to spot)- I've used PlatformEffector2Ds on TileMapColliders and they work as expected.

Comment: Could you try (a quick change, for the sake of this problem) changing your character's RB settings to Dynamic?

Comment: @andeart thanks for the suggestion! I gave it a try and changed it to dynamic. However, I'm still not able to have the character jump through the platforms one way. The interaction between character and tiles is the same.. Do you have a minimal example that I could reference which demonstrates one-way collision tile maps? That would be incredibly helpful - thank you!

Comment: I just set up a quick sandbox project. In an empty scene (make sure your code isn't in there to remove that doubt)- create a tilegrid in the scene, add a tile. Add the components setup from your screenshot. Create a Sprite,Rigidbody2d,BoxCollider2D,Dynamic setup on a new object. Place this object underneath the platform. Set its gravity scale to -1. Run the scene. Watch the object float up. After it crosses, while still in play mode, change the gravity back to 1. Confirm that the collider only goes one way and not the other.

Comment: @andeart Thanks again for the response and for the simple example! This setup worked as expected! I believe that the cause of my issue must be therefore be in the character/object controller script which is doing additional collision detection that I wasn't thinking about before. I will be able to debug this from here. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :) Do you mind selecting my response below as 'Answered' please? Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit turned out to be custom collision/physics code that OP had written separately (which I do not have access to).

We ran a few test cases. Confirmed that PlatformEffector2D does, in fact, work as expected on a TilemapCollider. No special steps needed to set it up.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, as the question is about how to achieve the one way collisions in a tilemap. He knows that it is not a Unity problem, but he is just describing the way he tried attempting to solve the problem before asking here. This answer doesn't help and IMHO should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Please give a summary of your comments discussion in this answer. That will help the new users as not everyone will look at the comments section.

Comment: That's a good point. Updating my answer.